# How can I switch from using Rails 2 (packaged) to Rails 3 (RVM)?

Tags: installation, rails, rvm

I've installed the Rails 2.3.14 package by running:

```
sudo apt-get install rails
```

It is working fine. But after that I installed the Rails 3.2.9 gem by running:

```
gem install rails
```

In the terminal, `rails -v` gives me `rails 2.3.14`. If I run these two commands,

```
. ~/.bash_profile
rails -v
```

then I get `rails 3.2.9`.

I don't know what exactly is happening. Now I want just the Rails 3.2.9 gem. What should I do to get that?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to uninstall Rails 2.3.14?

Try this: `gem uninstall rails` and it should show you all the versions and you pick the one you want to uninstall.

if that doesn't work try `sudo apt-get remove rails`

For more help try this thread as I'm in a similar boat trying to install rails correctly (just installed Ubuntu):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154498/rails-v-returns-2-3-5-but-gem-uninstall-rails-offers-to-uninstall-version-3-1

Answer (score 0):

Better to follow this blog to install Ruby on Rails this way as I didn't have any issues when I followed step by step the blog said: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/